# C# If else program not recognizing the if statement and only taking the else

Tags: c#, if-statement, directory

Hi i have the following code, the problem i am facing is no matter if the folder exists it still continues to send the email instead of ignoring to send it.

What can i change to get this working.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string yesterdaydate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyy-mm-dd");
        string[] SplitDate = yesterdaydate.Split('-');
        string year = SplitDate[0];
        string month = SplitDate[1];
        string day = SplitDate[2];
        string path = Path.Combine("C:\\Users\\ales\\Desktop\\test", year, month, day);

        if (Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            //do nothing
        }

        else
        {
            string fromAddress = "noreply@arm.com";
            string toAddress = "alese@arm.com";
            string subject = "error";
            string body = "failed to sync";

            krysalis_email.EmailClient email = new krysalis_email.EmailClient();
            krysalis_email.EmailClient.EmailResponse emailResponse = email.sendBasicMail(new object[] {toAddress}, fromAddress, subject, body, false, "smtp.za.arm.com",
                new string[] {"", ""}, false, null);


            if (emailResponse != null)
            {

            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: 100% an error in your path. Debug your code and check the `path` value. Furthermore you can use DateTime.Day/.Month/.Year properties to access the values you need without parsing a `string`.

Comment: As well as the answer someone gave, you likely don't have access to the other user's desktop folder, so `Directory.Exists()` is returning `false`. If it doesn't work after fixing the date format `MM`,  try running your program as an administrator.

Comment: Also it's not necessary to turn the date into a string and then extract the day/month/year components. Use DateTime.Day, .Month and .Year.

Comment: @Fildor I'm waiting to see if the other answer fixes the problem first...

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your date format to string. You are using `mm` which is minutes. Use `MM` to get month. Keep in mind that `MM` format will give you month with leading zero, for example `08`
If you want to use string splitting, then change the code to

```
string yesterdaydate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

But as others pointing, the better way to get values is to use `DateTime` instead of parsing string. Here is an example:

```
DateTime yesterdaydate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
string year = yesterdaydate.Year.ToString();
string month = yesterdaydate.Month.ToString("D2");//D2 to format number to be zero-padded
string day = yesterdaydate.Day.ToString("D2");
string path = Path.Combine("C:\\Users\\ales\\Desktop\\test", year, month, day);
```

Comment: Yes, I just thought adding that would make that answer even more useful.

Comment: @Fildor I just did that. Thanks

Comment: If the numbers in the folder names need to be zero-padded (which it seems is probably the case) you'll need to provide format strings to the `ToString` calls for month/day

Comment: Nice catch @pinkfloydx33. Thanks